# Socklen_t was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I was coding a c++ server on windows environment using some functions and types by the linux one.
Unfortunately I got the following error message when I declared a variable 'socklen_t': Socklen_t was not declared in this scope socklen_t addrlen;
How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: you are going to have to show code

Comment: windows != linux.  If you are trying to use a linux function on windows it probably wont work.  Please share a [mvce]

Comment: Check this [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You're probably missing a header file.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows API doesn't have or use `socklen_t`. Use `int` instead.

Make a `typedef` for `socklen_t` on Windows if you want to write portable code that compiles in different compilers across multiple platforms:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef int socklen_t;
#endif
```